# Line wrapping in visual studio for LaTeX code

Tags: visual-studio

Problem is when I write long sentences and proofs, all words stay at same line and text is horizontal too long and has low visibility. In TeXworks it would be wrapped in multiple lines but here it's all in one line.

Comment: can you clarify if you are taking about the behaviour of your editor or of the output?

Comment: behaviour of visual studio code